# Diseño de base de datos: Tabla detalle_facturas relacionada a distintas tablas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy realizando una base de datos de una **automotriz**, en la cual tengo que guardar datos de *facturacion*.

En esta automotriz se venden *vehiculos terminados* y a su vez, *autopartes*, cada una con su respectiva tabla.

Yo se que al hacer una BD para guardar esta informacion se necesita una tabla `facturas` relacionada a una `detalle_Facturas`, y en esta ultima podremos relacionar el `id` de los `productos` que estemos comerciando.

Ahora, en este caso debemos relacionar 2 tablas diferentes al mismo detalle.

Mi primera opcion fue vincular el `id` tanto de la tabla `vehiculos`, como autopartes en `detalle_facturas`, y dejar en `null` el `id` del vehiculo en caso de comprar una *autoparte* y viceversa.

Pero esto no seria correcto conceptualmente, por lo tanto:

- ¿Seria correcto tener dos tablas detalles(detalle_facturas_vehiculos y detalle_facturas_autopartes) vinculadas a una tabla facturas?
- ¿Que otras opciones podria utilizar?

Comment: Esto, asi como esta planteado, parece basado en opiniones.. pero porque pensas que un vehiculo es diferente a una autoparte? los dos son productos, no?